# show that two angles in a circumcircle are equal

Tags: geometry

We have the following circumcircle to ARP
where PR = PQ are tangents to the smaller circle

[image]

I need to show that the angle a = the angle b, which is equivalent to show that RP = AP', or show that the triangle formed by RA and the intersection between PA and RP' is an isosceles. Although this seems like it should be clear I'm not sure how to prove it in a rigorous way, any ideas?

Edit:
This may be the solution? Can anyone confirm?

[image]

Connect the points P and P', label the arc angles BR to f and g to AB.
Since g + f + b spans the whole arc length AP and g + f + a spans the whole arc length PR', it only makes sense that a and b are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Join BR and extend PR to K. Then, $\angle KRB = \angle BCR$ (angle in alternate segment)

(2) $\angle BCR = a + f$ (exterior angle of triangle ABC)

(3) $\angle KRB = f + b$ (exterior angle cyclic quad RBAP)